# A problem with user-defined literal operator (in raw mode)

Tags: c++, c++20, user-defined-literals

I am trying to define a literal operator in literal mode (i.e) the function parameter list should be `const char* arg1` only not `const char* arg1,size_t size` but I can't

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>




int operator"" _i(const char* charsArr){

        return std::stoi(std::string{charsArr});
    }


int main(){
        std::cout<<"1234324"_i;

        return 0;
    }
```

The compiler error message

```
error C3688: invalid literal suffix '_i'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""_i' not found
note: Literal operator must have a parameter list of the form 'const char *, std::size_t'
```

Comment: I guess your compiler doesn't support c++20

Comment: @AlanBirtles: That wouldn't work in C++20 either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDLs as applied to string literals only have one mode (2 in C++20, but the new one is not applicable to your case): you get a pointer and a size. Only non-string UDLs have a single-argument `const char*` form.

That is, string literals in C++ can contain embedded NUL characters, and your UDLs aren't allowed to pretend otherwise.

Comment: So, If on deleting the two quotes in `std::cout<<"1234324"_i;`, the code compiles and 1234324 will be recieved as const `char*` (c style array) in the operator function??

Comment: @anonymous: Yes. But you wouldn't need the `_i` at all. What is the problem with getting a size for the string anyway? Just do it the right way.

Comment: I just wanted to check something